# IntelliJ - How to jump to source instead of compiled classes from failed unit tests in the "Run" view

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, intellij-idea

When I run my JUnit tests in IntelliJ and one of them fails, I would like to jump to the source code of the failing test by double-clicking it (or by right-clicking it and selecting "Jump to source" or "Show source") in the results view (in the list of failed tests in the "Run" view). However, this feature doesn't always work correctly. Sometimes the source code is shown and sometimes only the compiled ".class" file of the test is shown to me in the editor window. 
I would always like to see the source code (".java" file) instead of the ".class" file in the editor window after double-clicking the failed test. 
One solution for it is to click "Attach Sources..." in the editor window, where the ".class" file of the test class is displayed. However, I have to do it for every test file and it takes much time to do it repeatedly for every test. In my opinion IntelliJ should find the source code automatically, because it's present in my Project (it's my own class and its source code is in the project and I run this test from the Project view, where the classes with source code are visible). How can I configure IntelliJ, so that it finds the source code automatically for every unit test which I run?

The ".class" files which are shown instead of the ".java" files are contained in a jar file which is built by Maven.

Comment: Try running in debug view. Are java files deployed directly or you have jar containing classes?

Comment: @Gayathri: The ".class" files which are shown instead of the ".java" files are contained in a jar file which is built by Maven.

Comment: So that's the reason why class files are shown, your jar contains only class files and not java file. Compiled code is not available in intellij as that doesn't decompile it. may be you can try to look up that line with jar opened in a java decompiler.

Comment: @Gayathri: I don't have to look up the source code using a decompiler, because I've written it by myself and it's contained in my IntelliJ project as java files. The java files contained in my project are compiled by Maven to the jar files. It's not an external library, it's my own project.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can map class to java file in that case. As far as I understand once you create a jar, jar contains only class file. to look up in java file you need to got to the code which generated the class file manually. Also, If the jar is created by you, you can have unit tests in the module which created the jar and verify that.

Comment: @Gayathri: I don't understand what you mean. In my opinion, IntelliJ should be intelligent enough to track the source from which it generated the jar files. IntelliJ is able to jump to the source code from the console if there is a path to a method in the console. However, it SOMETIMES (i.e. not always) isn't able to jump to the source code from the executed JUnit test methods which are listed in the "Run" view.

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to go to the External Libraries in your Project view (File > Project Structure), find the jar that contains the .class file, and right click (or F4). You will see Open Library Settings. From that dialog, you can attach a src folder to the library. [image]

Comment: And if your module containing the class file is in the intellij project, it may also be possible that the pom version declared for the module in your parent pom, references an older version of the project.

Comment: As I mentioned in the description of my question, I know this solution (in a slightly different way, because the "Attach Sources..." appears in the upper right corner of the editor window, but it's the same mechanism) and as I've also written in the description, I would expect IntelliJ to be more "intelligent" and to discover the java source files which are contained in my project, which are compiled to the class files. The ".java" and ".class" files which I mean aren't files of external libraries, but they are files written by me in the same project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 ultimate edition and faced this issue, debugger would jump to decompiled .class files
On the top right corner once your debugger jumps to .class file  [image]

you will see an option to 'choose sources', choose the directory which has your .java file. Worked for me atleast.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. In my case it was due to incorrect Module configuration. Basically you must ensure that the source folder containing the java files is added to `Sources` tab in corresponding module.

To do this Go to `Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S)` and select `Modules`. Choose corresponding module and verify that the source folder containing the java files is correctly added to the `Sources Folders`. If it is not then add it.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue today. The solution for me was to right click on main pom.xml, then maven, then reimport.

Answer (score 2):

I Had a similar issue. The issue was still there even after pointing to the correct source folder but I got rid of it by setting the classes folder to the source code's root folder.

[image]

Comment: This solved the problem for me. The only annoying side effect now is that the source code's root folder is highlighted Yellow in the project navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a solution to JAVA Maven project.

Open 'Libraries' from 'Project settings', search and select the Java jar you want to attach source file. Then you can add source directory by click the '+' button.

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar issue. The solution for me was to close project, delete .idea folder than re open the project.