# IntelliJ ctrl-click references a .class file not a .java file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following line of code in a .groovy file for testing:

```
GenerateShipConfirmsForBatch gscb = new GenerateShipConfirmsForBatch();
```

Ctrl-clicking on the GenerateShipConfirmsForBatch takes me to GenerateShipConfirmsForBatch.class in a .jar, and not the .java file, even though I have the class correctly imported at the top.  I want it to reference the .java file so it will pick up changes I make to the .java file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: because you don't download the source code for this repo, you need to download the source code. Or the Intellij will decompile the class file to source code (I think you can see one warning on the top of the file)

Comment: If you want to edit this code, `GenerateShipConfirmsForBatch.java` file must be present in one of the source roots of your project.

Comment: Do you have access to the .java file?

Comment: Please follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846588/2065796).

Answer (score 5):

## First guess - *Wrong import*

What you wrote seems to me like you have class with the same name in 2 different packages or in imported project instead of in open-able java class. When you import class be careful that you import the one you want to use.

*Eg. annotation class Service is wildly used in different packages.*

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Service;
```

Just check that you are using the correct import.

## Second guess - *Incorrectly set modules*

If you are having the multi-module application you have to set correctly the parent project to properly address this issue as well as child projects where the links should be as well.

In **Maven** it is done using `pom.xml`. It is very nicely addressed in [Maven - Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

In **Gradle**  it is done using `build.gradle`. You can read more about it [Gradle Multi-Module Project Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9013597/4745695).

---

## Basics about classes

### Local class

Idea is linking local `.java` files in preference instead of `.class` therefore if this is happening I'd recommend reinstalling Idea as I cannot find the correct approach.

### Linked class (from external library)

If you have imported external library it WILL link to `.class` as it is decompiled from `.jar` file.

What you can do is either download `.jar` with source codes, if you are using `Maven Projects` click on `Download Sources and/or Documentation`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have the class imported at the top does not mean that you can view the source code (e.g., `.java` file). If this class is coming from a dependency defined in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file then you likely won't have access to view the source code. However, if this is a separate module you have at the top level of your project, then you'll be able to view the `.java` file. If this library is open source then I'd suggest cloning it in your project and adding it as a module. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Java Decompiler IntelliJ Plugin** from here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7100-java-decompiler-intellij-plugin

It allows you to display all the Java sources during your debugging process, even if you do not have them all